# Selecting required fields using relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model `Meetings` like this:

```
public function meeting_comments(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\MeetingsComments', 'meeting_id', 'id');
    }

    public function meeting_users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserMeetingDetails', 'meeting_id', 'id');
    }
```

The Controller is like this:

```
$res = Meetings::with('meeting_comments', 'meeting_users')
                        ->select('')->get()->toArray();
```

I only need `comments` from `meeting_comments` and `user_id` from `meeting_users`.
What do I put in `select` to only get the required fields from `meeting_comments` and `meeting_users` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it through a closure in the with call:

```
$res = Meetings::with(['meeting_comments' => function($query) {
        $query->select('comments', 'meeting_id');
    }, 'meeting_users' => function($query) {
        $query->select('user_id', 'meeting_id');
    }])
    ->get()->toArray();
```

I'm taking this from memory, so the syntax may be slightly incorrect, but it should work. :)

Comment: The foreign key must be added to the select, otherwise Laravel will not be able to match the related Collections with each other.

Comment: @patricus Ah, I see. Thanks for the correction. If you'd like to post a better answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nah, yours is good. Just need to add the 'meeting_id' field to both selects. :)